# PHP Json see if value exist

Tags: php, json

I've been looking all over the *interwebz* for a simple answer but can't find any. So, the question is:

I'm going to decode some JSON to see if a value exists; though, I don't think I'm doing it right. I want to check if the value of appid: 730 exists.

Here's the JSON:

```
{
response: {
    game_count: 106,
        games: [
            {
            appid: 10,
            playtime_forever: 67
            },
            {
            appid: 730,
            playtime_forever: 0
            },
            {
            appid: 368900,
            playtime_forever: 0
            },
            {
            appid: 370190,
            playtime_forever: 0
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

This is what I want:

```
$json = file_get_contents('JSON URL HERE');
$msgArray = json_decode($json, true);

if (appid: 730 exists) {
   ...
}
```

Thanks, hope I explained enough.

Comment: 1. Use `$msgArray` in a foreach, and look down the tree for `games` array.

Comment: the `json` is not responding... [Invalid Json](https://3v4l.org/ld9Oa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you have invalid json.  See the comment in the string deceleration below (this might be a typo in your question).

```
$json = '{
"response": {
    "game_count": 106,
    "games": [
        {
            "appid": 10,
            "playtime_forever": 67
        },
        {
            "appid": 730,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        {
            "appid": 368900,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        {
            "appid": 370190,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        } // <------ note the lack of `,`
        ]
    }
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($arr['response']['games'] as $game) {
    if($game['appid'] === 730) { // I would strictly check (type) incase of 0
        echo "exists"; // or do something else
        break; // break out if you dont care about the rest
    }
}
```

[example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/727717a7470ade16d4ed40650d32afaadf614ab9)

We're just looping through the games array and checking its `appid`.  Then we just do something and then break the loop to prevent overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution quite straight forward:

```
$r='{
"response": {
    "game_count": 106,
        "games": [
            {
            "appid": 10,
            "playtime_forever": 67
            },
            {
            "appid": 730,
            "playtime_forever": 0
            },
            {
            "appid": 368900,
            "playtime_forever": 0
            },
            {
            "appid": 370190,
            "playtime_forever": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}';

function find($arr, $id) {
    if(!empty($arr))
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if( isset( $value->appid ) && $value->appid == $id )
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}

$obj = json_decode($r);
if( isset($obj) && isset($obj->response) ) {
    if( isset($obj->response->games) && !empty($obj->response->games) )
        $arr = $obj->response->games;
    else
        $arr = array();
} else {
    echo "NOT valid found\n";
}

$appid = 730;

if( find($arr, $appid) )
    echo "Appid $appid found\n";
else
    echo "Appid $appid NOT found\n";
```

It is **very convenient** to parse and validate the results coming from other Web Services before accessing their data, so we avoid and development time.

I hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_decode()
```

is actually going to return the decoded JSON. JSON is a string, decoded JSON is an array of objects.

You will need to iterate over that array of objects to inspect each.

```
$msgArray = json_decode($json);

foreach($msgArray->response->games as $game) {
   if($game->appid == 730) {
      // it exists
   }
}
```

Comment: he's using the true flag for the second parameter, making it an array of data as opposed to an object of data.

Comment: ok...I don't think that's his problem though. I'm just trying to direct him toward looking at each data entity in the data structure that results from decoding the json.

Comment: Well, just don't want him to get confused on the different types if he's been told by someone else to use Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$json = file_get_contents('JSON URL HERE');
$msgArray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($msgArray['response']['games'] as $key => $value){
  if ($value['appid'] == 730) {
   //do something
  }else{
   // do else
  }
}
```

Comment: `$value.appid` is incorrect, and more for JS than PHP. Correct would be `$value['appid']`